# Consulta con DataGridView

Tags: c#, windows-forms, checkbox, datagridview

tengo una consulta con respecto a ítems seleccionados por medio de un `CheckBox` dentro de `DataGridView`. La cosa es que, cargo mi `DataGridView` y le añado `CheckBoxes`. Lo que sucede es que tengo un `TextBox` que ayuda a filtrar cuando presiono números para filtrar todo va bien pero cuando los borro los `CheckBox` cambian de posición y se deseleccionan los `CheckBox`. Adjunto un `GIF` de referencia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como verán, los `CheckBox` cambian de lugar al momento de filtrar y se deseleccionan. ¿Alguno tiene idea de como solucionar eso?

Dejo el método con el cual filtro:

```
private void filtrarTitulo(string valor)
        {
            SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection();
            conexion.ConnectionString = "cadena de conexión";
            conexion.Open();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Titulo FROM V_CuetaWeb WHERE Titulo LIKE ('" + valor + "%') ORDER BY Titulo DESC", conexion);
            da.Fill(ds, "Cuotas");
            conexion.Close();
            dtgTitulo.DataSource = ds;
            dtgTitulo.DataMember = "Cuotas";
        }
```

Dónde lo uso:

```
private void txtTitulo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            filtrarTitulo(txtTitulo.Text.ToString().Trim());
        }
```

Cómo asigno los `CheckBox` al `DataGridView`:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            llenaTitulo();

            DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chk = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
            chk.HeaderText = "Seleccione";
            chk.Name = "check";
            dtgTitulo.Columns.Add(chk);
            dtgTitulo.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        }
```

Y como cargo el `DataGridView`:

```
public void llenaTitulo()
        {
            try
            {
                string conn = "cadena de conexión";
                using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(conn))
                {
                    conexion.Open();
                    string query = "SELECT Titulo AS Título FROM V_CuetaWeb GROUP BY Titulo ORDER BY Titulo DESC";
                    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conexion);
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    dtgTitulo.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    conexion.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

**Problema uno:** `Se cambian de lugar los ChckcBox`

**Problema dos:** `Se deseleccionan los CheckBox`

¿Alguna sugerencia?

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

```
private void filtrarTituloDos(string valor)
        {
            List<DataGridViewRow> filtro = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in dtgTitulo.Rows)
            {
                //Asumo que el campo a filtrar se llama Titulo
                //Filtramos las filas con campo Titulo igual a valor
                if (fila.Cells["Título"].Value.ToString() == valor)
                {
                    filtro.Add(fila);
                }
            }
            //Borrrando todas la filas actuales del DataGridView
            dtgTitulo.Rows.Clear();

            foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in filtro)
            {
                //Agregamos las filas filtradas al DataGridView
                dtgTitulo.Rows.Add(fila);
            }
        }

private void txtTitulo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblCaracterTitulo.Text = Convert.ToString(8 - txtTitulo.Text.Length);
            filtrarTituloDos(txtTitulo.Text.ToString().Trim());
        }
```

**Problema 1:** `System.ArgumentException: 'No se puede borrar esta lista.'` en la línea: `dtgTitulo.Rows.Clear();` al momento de escribir en el `TextBox` para filtrar

**Problema 2:** Si comento la línea del problema anterior, sucede que no filtra nada. **¿Sugerencias?**

Comment: Estas volviendo a cargar el listado, cuando filtras.

Comment: Disculpa, no entiendo @RamiroBarone

Comment: Usas llenaTitulo()  como primera carga de datos. Luego cuando filtras usas filtrarTitulo(string valor) le estas pasando nueva información al grid.

Comment: Y, ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo? @RamiroBarone

Comment: Si cargas una base de datos y la asignas a un ´DataGridView´, luego agregas una columna de tipo ´DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn´, llamada ´chk´, sin que sus valores estén asociados a un campo de la base de datos, cuando haces una consulta, para aplicar un filtro, la columna ´chk´ estará incluida en tu ´DataGridView´, tomará para su propiedad ´Checked´ valores predeterminados que es false, pues en tu código, nada les establece su valor, si quieres lograr lo que planteas tendrás que almacenar ese valor booleano en alguna variable de tu código, lo más aconsejable seria en la propia base de datos.

Comment: Claro, el problema es que yo no tengo permisos para modificar esa base de datos y lo que uso para cargar el DTG es una vista. @EduardoReyes

Comment: En tu pregunta planteas que haces una consulta con respecto a ´ítems seleccionados por medio de un ´CheckBox´pero lo cierto es que no veo que hagas nada con el valor del ´CheckBox´, la consulta que haces ´SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Titulo FROM V_CuetaWeb WHERE Titulo LIKE ('" + valor + "%') ORDER BY Titulo DESC", conexion);´ solo toma en cuenta el parámetro valor, que es el texto editado en tu ´TextBox´. No entiendo que pretendes hacer realmente con los valores del ´CheckBox´.

Comment: A los valores seleccionados los utilizo para enviar mensajes de manera masiva. Es por eso que necesito saber como mantengo los `items` seleccionados luego de filtrarlos. Si busco el registro: 107501 y le marco el `check`, luego busco el registro 109001 y le marco el `check`, necesito que ese `check`sea persistente hasta que se presione el botón. Pero, como muestro en el GIF si busco un registro en el `TextBox` el `check` que marqué se destilda. @EduardoReyes

Comment: Creo entender lo que quieres lograr, pero para que los artículos que se muestran después de aplicado el filtro, mantengan el estado que tenían, debes implementar una forma de pasarle al `DataGridView` los valores para la columna `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`, eso no lo puedes lograr asignándole `dtgTitulo.DataSource = ds;` pues la base de datos, no tiene un campo asociado a esta columna, una variante seria hacer el filtro manualmente en tu código.

Comment: Lo intenté utilizando un `bindingsource` pero al ser un valor float me genera problemas y pues ni compilar puedo

Comment: El error esta el textChange, debería de implementarse de diferente forma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te coloco una variante que se puede usar para resolver tu problema, observa que creo un `DataGridView`, solo para mostrar los `items` filtrados, le asigno la mismas ubicación y tamaño del `dtgTitulo`, lo que implica que se mostrará superpuesto sobre el `DataGridView dtgTitulo`, pero puedes darle otra ubicación, incluso pudieras mostrarlo en otro formulario como una ventana emergente.

```
//Declarando un DataGridView, para mostrar los items filtrados
private DataGridView dataFiltro;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            llenaTitulo();

            DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chk = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
            chk.HeaderText = "Seleccione";
            chk.Name = "check";
            dtgTitulo.Columns.Add(chk);
            dtgTitulo.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            //Crear el DataGridView que mostrará el filtro.
            dataFiltro = new DataGridView();
            dataFiltro.Location = dtgTitulo.Location;
            dataFiltro.Size = dtgTitulo.Size;
            dataFiltro.Visible = false;
            this.Controls.Add(dataFiltro);
}
```

El procedimiento  `filtrarTitulo`.

```
      private void filtrarTitulo(string valor)
        {
                        List<DataGridViewRow> filtro = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in dtgTitulo.Rows)
        {
            //Asumo que el campo a filtrar se llama Titulo
            //Filtramos las filas con campo Titulo igual a valor
            if (fila.Cells["Titulo"].Value!=null && fila.Cells["Titulo"].Value.ToString() == valor)
            {
                filtro.Add(fila);
            }
        }
        //Borrando todas la columnas actuales del DataGridView dataFiltro
        dataFiltro.Columns.Clear();
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn columna in dtgTitulo.Columns)
        {
            //Agregamos columnas clonadas al DataGridView dataFiltro
            if (columna is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn)
            {
                int index = dataFiltro.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn());
                dataFiltro.Columns[index].Name = columna.Name;
                dataFiltro.Columns[index].HeaderText = columna.HeaderText;
            }
            else
                dataFiltro.Columns.Add(columna.Name, columna.HeaderText);
        }


        foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in filtro)
        {
            //Agregamos las filas filtradas al DataGridView dataFiltro
           int rowindex = dataFiltro.Rows.Add();
           int columindex = 0;
           foreach (DataGridViewCell celda in fila.Cells)
           {
               if (celda.Value != null)
               {
                   dataFiltro[columindex, rowindex].Value = celda.Value;
               }
               columindex++;
           }
        }
        //Colocamos la propiedad visible a true
        dataFiltro.Visible = true;
        //Lo traemos al frente, se mostrará sobre el DataGridView dtgTitulo
         dataFiltro.BringToFront();
        }
```

En tu código original haces la llamada al procedimiento `filtrarTitulo` en el evento `TextChanged` del `TextBox`, eso no es conveniente, pues estarias ejecutando la llamada cada ves que el usuario presione una tecla, te recomiendo agregar un boton que el usuario pueda presionar cuando termine de escribir el texto y desee aplicar el filtro.

```
   private void buttonAplicarFiltro_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if(txtTitulo.Text!="")
      {
         lblCaracterTitulo.Text = Convert.ToString(8 - txtTitulo.Text.Length);
   filtrarTitulo(txtTitulo.Text.ToString().Trim());
      }
    }
```

Además en tu procedimiento `llenaTitulo`, debes hacer lo siguiente, además de todo lo que ya tienes hecho.

```
public void llenaTitulo()
        {
          //Aquí deja todo el código que tienes escrito en este procedimiento.

         //Aquí agrega lo siguiente.
          //Traer al frente el DataGridView dtgTitulo
          dtgTitulo.BringToFront();
          //Ocultar el DataGridView dataFiltro
          dataFiltro.Visible = false;
        }
```

Comment: En la línea: `dataFiltro.Columns.Add(columna.Clone());` me dice `no se puede convertir de 'object' a 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn'`

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo Edité la respuesta, son funciones que no había empleado, pero se trata  de que habría que hacer la conversión adecuada en cada caso; me queda la duda de si la linea de código `dataFiltro.Rows.Add(fila.Clone() as DataGridViewRow);` funcionará adecuadamente, si no funciona, habra que realizar un `foreach` por las celdas de cada fila y agregar los valores uno a uno. Prueba  si da error me comentas.

Comment: En esta línea: `dataFiltros.Columns.Add(columna.Clone() as DataGridTextBoxColumn);` el error es: 
`no se puede convertir de 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridTextBoxColumn' a 'System.Windows.Forms.DatagridViewColumn'`

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo Pues ponle dataFiltros.Columns.Add(columna.Clone() as DatagridViewColumn) y prueba si funciona.

Comment: Pues, lo que hace es que al escribir en el TextBox desaparezcan todos los datos del datagridview

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo Edité la respueta, cambié el código del procedimiento `filtrarTitulo`, con una variante que implementé, la compilé, la probé y funcionó. Pruebala y me notificas.

Answer (score 1):

te parece si en el metodo llenatitulo() pones también el código de las columnas checkbox:

```
 DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chk = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
            chk.HeaderText = "Seleccione";
            chk.Name = "check";
            dtgTitulo.Columns.Add(chk);
            dtgTitulo.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

Me parece que esa seria la solución. Slds

Comment: Hmm, no. Eso consigue que se dupliquen las columnas de `CheckBox`

Comment: osea creo que deberías eliminar el código del Form1_load ya que estarían en el método  llenatitulo()

Comment: Eso es lo que hice y carga el form así: `check / dato / check`

Answer (score 1):

Te coloco un ejemplo de lo que haría sin emplear bases de datos ni otros objetos:

```
    private void filtrarTitulo(string valor)
    {
        List<DataGridViewRow> filtro = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in dtgTitulo.Rows)
        {
            //Asumo que el campo a filtrar se llama Titulo
            //Filtramos las filas con campo Titulo igual a valor
            if (fila.Cells["Titulo"].Value.ToString() == valor)
            {
                filtro.Add(fila);
            }
        }
        //Borrrando todas la filas actuales del DataGridView
        dtgTitulo.Rows.Clear();

        foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in filtro)
        {
            //Agregamos las filas filtradas al DataGridView
            dtgTitulo.Rows.Add(fila);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Bien, lo que hice fue añadir esta línea: `llenaTitulo()` debajo de esta: `List<DataGridViewRow> filtro = new List<DataGridViewRow>();` y el punto a corregir es que esta al compilar sale este error: `'No se puede borrar esta lista.'` en la línea: `dtgTitulo.Rows.Clear();`

Comment: Cuando comento esa línea, al momento de filtrar sale el siguiente error cuando quiero filtrar con el textbox: `'No se pueden agregar filas mediante programación a la colección de filas de DataGridView cuando el control está enlazado a datos.'`

Comment: No entiendo para que necesitas añadir esta línea: `llenaTitulo()` debajo de esta: `List<DataGridViewRow> filtro = new List<DataGridViewRow>();` fijate que el ejemplo que te coloqué en mi respuesta es para sustituir tu código en el procedimiento `private void filtrarTitulo(string valor)`, se supone que ya hiciste una llamada a `llenaTitulo()` en tu procedimiento `private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` no necesitas volverlo a hacer al momento de aplicar el filtro.

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo Está claro que no te permitirá agregar ni eliminar filas si el control está enlazado a datos, no tuve en cuenta ese detalle en mi respuesta, pero para habilitarla te recomiendo crear un nuevo `DataGridView` solo para mostrar los `items` filtrados. Recuerda agregar ese nuevo  `DataGridView` a tu formulario.

Comment: Vale, mira, he actualizado la pregunta con tu método para que se entienda lo que ambos tratamos de decir. Porque capaz me explico mal

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo Agregué una nueva respuesta, con más detalles de como crear otro `DataGridView`y pasarle los `items` filtrados, espero que te funcione y te sirva para solucionar tu problema.